# How to filter a Column and delete a Row in Dataset Spark using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, filtering, apache-spark-dataset

I need to filter a Dataset searching for Special Characters and remove the row where it was found.
I tried to replace the special character with " ", but it doesn't worked either.

```
Dataset<row> dataset;
dataset.withColumn("nameColumn", function.regex_replace(dataset.col("nameColumn"), "[^\\p{ASCII}]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just filter them:

```java
filitered_ds = dataset.where(!col("nameColumn").rlike("[^\p{ASCII}]"))
```

Comment: Thank you, friend!
What I did was:

String pattern = "^\\\\u0000-\\\\u007F]*$";

Dataset<Row> datasetFiltered = T.where(T.col("columnName".rlike(pattern));